# Анимация android, ошибка CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, анимация

Мне надо запустить анимацию `imageview`, а именно rotate animation в отдельном потоке. Для этого я реализовал интерфейс `Runnable`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotateanimation);
    button.startAnimation(animation); //<--- 176 строка в дебаге
   }
}
```

И конечно же анимация -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Так же реализовал интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toggleGreenLed:
            try {
                int value = 0;

                value = (greenButton.isChecked() ? 1 : 0) + 130;
                OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                outStream.write(value);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.connect: // вот эту кнопку нажимаем, чтобы запустить анимацию этой же кнопки     
            Thread thread = new Thread(this)
            thread.start();//запускаем метод run()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Подождите...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            tryConnectToWatch(); //инициализация bluetooth
            break;
    }
}
```

Вот собственно результат работы исключение:

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Если честно все перелазил, пробовал способы для устранения - не помогало. Жду помощи, заранее спасибо

```
public void tryConnectToWatch() { //
    if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        try {

            BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice("20:16:08:16:14:57");
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
            clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            clientSocket.connect();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Браслет подключен успешно.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText("Устройство подключено");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Запуск анимации и метода tryConnectTowatch()

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toggleGreenLed:
            try {
                int value = 0;

                value = (greenButton.isChecked() ? 1 : 0) + 130;
                OutputStream outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                outStream.write(value);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.connect:
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    tryConnectToWatch();
                }
            });
            button.startAnimation(animation);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Подождите...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исключение

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

говорит о том, что Вы взаимодействуете с UI не из того потока, который этот UI создал, чего делать нельзя.

Как вариант, код, манипулирующий UI, можно запустить в главном потоке таким образом:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    // some actions

    }
});
```

Comment: Это сработало,но есть еще одна проблема. Почему-то когда я нажимаю на эту кнопку, сначала происходит инициализация устройства bluetooth, а потом когда она завершилась - анимация. Почему так? Ведь в отдельном потоке создавалось.

Comment: А Вам анимацию принципиально в стороннем потоке запускать?

Comment: Иначе я не вижу способа. Инициализация всегда идет первой, не важно в каком месте стоит метод вызывающий ее.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам стоит инициализировать bluetooth в отдельном потоке, а не анимацию... Ведь инициализация bluetooth может "подтормаживать" основной поток где идет анимация.

**Обновление**

Вам нужно делать ваш коннект к браслету в отдельном потоке, у вас сейчас все в основном. Если сделать так, то анимация глючить не будет, только учтите что вы с потока не сможете менять ваши вьюшки

```
textView.setText("Устройство подключено");
```

так что нужно использовать что-то либо `AsyncTask` (хорошо что с коробки идет) или `RxJava`, хорошая библиотека, которой удобно организовать многопоточность.

Comment: На самом деле это все очень странно, та же история. С этой инициализацией что-то не то. Может она все приложение полностью тормозит?

Comment: а что у вас там? дайте пример кода

Comment: подправил вопрос, в самом низу