# Вылетает приложение при вызове TextView.text =

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textview

Вылетает приложение при изменение текста внутри Thread

```
    private fun sendEmail() {
    try {
        val properties = System.getProperties()

        properties["mail.smtp.host"] = host;
        properties["mail.smtp.port"] = "465"
        properties["mail.smtp.ssl.enable"] = "true"
        properties["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"

        val session = Session.getInstance(properties, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication(user, password)
            }
        })
        val mimeMessage = MimeMessage(session)

        mimeMessage.setFrom(InternetAddress("terminallen300@yandex.ru"))

        mimeMessage.addRecipient(
            Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress("agladysev404@gmail.com")
        )
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(
            Message.RecipientType.CC,
            InternetAddress("msaigla@ya.ru")
        )

        mimeMessage.subject = "Перемещение по складам"
        var msg = "<html>\n" +
                "  <head>\n" +
                "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "    <title>Моя тестовая страница</title>\n" +
                "  </head>\n" +
                "  <body>\n" +
                "<p>"
        for (item in items) msg += item.etArticle.text.toString() + "\n"
        msg += "</p>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>"
        mimeMessage.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        thread {
            try {
                bc.status.text = "Статус: Отправляем"
                Transport.send(mimeMessage)
                bc.status.text = "Статус: Отправлено"
            } catch (e: MessagingException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error 3")
                println(e)
                bc.status.text = "Статус: Ошибка"
            }
        }


    } catch (e: AddressException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error 1")
    } catch (e: MessagingException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error 2")
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.readingbarcode, PID: 16242
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:9619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1917)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3605)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:26282)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:10076)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6621)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6441)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6393)
        at com.example.readingbarcode.MainActivity$sendEmail$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:104)
        at com.example.readingbarcode.MainActivity$sendEmail$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:102)
        at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16242 SIG: 9
```

Изменил на:

```
var status : String = "отправляется"
        var s: Boolean = true
        bc.status.text = "Статус: $status"
        runBlocking {
            thread {
                try {
                    Transport.send(mimeMessage)
                    Log.d("GOOD", "send")
                    status = "Отправлено"
                    s = false
                } catch (e: MessagingException) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error 3")
                    status = "Ошибка"
                    println(e)
                    s = false
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error 3")
                    status = "Ошибка"
                    s = false
                }
            }
            while (s) delay(100) 
        }
        bc.status.text = "Статус: $status"
```

Comment: есть еще какие-то ошибки? насколько я вижу Вы пытаетесь и отдельного трейта записывать во View напрямую это делать не получиться

Comment: Добавил в вопрос полный код и ошибку. Как я могу исправить эту часть кода?

Comment: CalledFromWrongThreadException вам говорит, что любые манипуляции с UI возможны только из главного потока приложения.

Comment: @and070995, здесь уже давали ответ на ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576601